# How to sniff communication between SSL protected Metro web service and WCF client?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, fiddler, packet-sniffers

**Environment**: NetBeans 7.0.1, GlassFish 3.1

I want to sniff the communication between a WCF (.NET Framework 4) client and a Metro (2.1.1) web service, and then check the messages to be sure everything is how I want it to be. The web service uses Transport Security (SSL). I already know of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), but I did not have any success using it; only HTTPS browser traffic was visible. Is there a way to set up Fiddler to capture traffic between my services? Is there any other way?

**UPDATE**

I tried to start client and server on different machines and then use Fiddler, but no success. I tried Wireshark to capture traffic, but did not have any success running both on localhost. If i tried them on different machines, all I could see was TCP data exchange between the services.

On localhost + Wireshark, the packet counter next to the interfaces remained the same however I was calling the service lots of times.

**UPDATE2**

Tried to set up the proxy for NetBeans manually in the options, and programatically, but no success:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost"); 
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888"); 
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "localhost"); 
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
```

Tried to start GlassFish with these JVM options, but no :( :

```
<jvm-options>-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dhttp.proxyPort=8888</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dhttps.proxyPort=8888</jvm-options>
```

Comment: Yes Fiddler works for services as well. How did you configure system to use Fiddler as a proxy or how did you configure WCF client to use it?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka I just tried it by trusting Fiddlers Root certificate. I did not set anything else. Do I need to use Fiddlers certificate on the service side?

Comment: Configure Fiddler as a proxy in IE and it should be used by the client automatically.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka It's configured as a proxy in IE by default, and no web service related messages are visible in Fiddler :(

Comment: Are both the client and service on the same computer?

Comment: @John Saunders Yes. Tried to call both 'localhost', '127.0.0.1' and computer name.

Comment: Read the Fiddler faq about how to trace localhost

Comment: @John Saunders Tried a few things from there, but they did not help. I turned off SSL, and still I can't see any web service traffic. However if I check the Glassfish Admin (`http://localhost:4848/`) in my browser I can see that in Fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to Fiddler, if you control the WCF client, you could enable [WCF Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx), and it will save all the unencrypted SOAP messages to a trace log. The logging can be enabled in the app.config file, so you don't even have to rebuild the app to enable or disable the logging.

Comment: Thanks! This works, however I see only request messages. I would prefer to see the whole exchange.

Comment: I can see the responses now. Deleted `maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"` from configuration, so it's the default `Int32.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 1):

you can setup metro to dump SOAP messages, info [here](http://metro.java.net/guide/Logging.html).  personally, i use [charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to watch soap exchanges.  you configure the java proxy using the system properties in your "update2", works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://portswigger.net/burp/
It has a proxy. The proxy can be used for viewing the http traffic. It can also display SSL traffic by generating self signed certificate on the fly. You need to import the generated certificate into the java key store at the jax-ws client. Ensure that you have enabled "Support invisible proxy for non-proxy aware clients"

Answer (score 0):

I often use commview to monitor traffic over the local loopback adapter. One of the few tools allowing traffic capture when both your client and service are on the same computer.

You can download a trail at http://www.tamos.com/products/commview/ and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

May be [WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Webscarab) is what you need. There are many manuals for sniffing ssl traffic, for instance [that](http://randomsync.blogspot.com/2010/07/intercepting-ssl-traffic-using.html).

Answer (score 0):

One approach I've tried successfully, is to make sure SSLv2 is used (as opposed to SSLv3), and then use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) as described on [the SSL page on the Wikishark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL), but better on [Citrix support page "How to decrypt SSL and TLS traffic using Wireshark "](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116557).  This works by giving Wireshark the private key of the server's SSL certificate, so that it can decrypt the conversation.

To force SSLv2 in your scenario, it seems sufficient to set `-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv2Hello` on your server-side JVM, but I googled that together.  (See, e.g., the "Why do I get a javax.net.ssl.SSLException" question on [the Java 1.4.2 Troubleshooting page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/faq/troubleshooting.html), and the part on `https.protocols` in the [JavaTM Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) Reference Guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html).)  I haven't done this part myself, and I can't seem to find clear documentation on this point.

(P.S. In my case, when I was decrypting .NET-to-.NET SSL traffic, I thought it was the switch back to SSLv2 which made the traffic readable by Wireshark.  However, [this blog post](https://wirewatcher.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/decrypting-ssl-traffic-with-wireshark-and-ways-to-prevent-it/) suggests that I was switching at the same time from a Diffie-Hellman cipher to a non-DH one.)